# How can I project an arbitrary line to the edges of the screen?

Tags: c++, math, geometry

What I'd like to be able to do is be given any two points (in the typical screen coordinate system where X increases to the right and Y increases downard) and return the two points where if that line were extended it would hit the edge of the screen. The method I have attempted here is to first translate the points to quadrant 1 (where Y increases upwardly) and then compute the y intercept of the line. If it is on the screen, then use it with a 0 X value. If it is off the screen, then the line must be crossing the X axis first... so the Y in that case would be 0 and the x is the x intercept. I then translate all the points to quadrant 3 and do the same thing. This same procedure should then return the point for the other end of my line.

The code appears to work in quadrant 1, but returns strange results for quadrant 3. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

float _line_slope( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 )
{
    return ((float)(y1-y2)) / ((float)(x1-x2));
}

float _y_intercept( float m, int x, int y )
{
    // y = mx + b
    float mx = m * x;

    // we need to get b by itself, so if mx is positive we need to subtract it from y,
    // if its negative we need to add it to y

    return (mx > 0.0) ? (float)y - mx : (float)y + mx;
}

float _x_intercept( float m, float b )
{
    return -b / m;
}

void _screen_to_quad1( uint32_t w, uint32_t h, int& x, int& y )
{
    y = (h - y);
}

void _quad1_to_screen( uint32_t w, uint32_t h, int& x, int& y )
{
    y = (h - y);
}

void _screen_to_quad3( uint32_t w, uint32_t h, int& x, int& y )
{
    x = (x - w);
    y = -y;
}

void _quad3_to_screen( uint32_t w, uint32_t h, int& x, int& y )
{
    x = (x + w);
    y = abs(y);
}

struct point { int x; int y; };

void _sort_points( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, struct point& a, struct point& b )
{
    if( x1 < x2 )
    {
        a.x = x1; a.y = y1;
        b.x = x2; b.y = y2;
    }
    else
    {
        a.x = x2; a.y = y2;
        b.x = x1; b.y = y1;
    }
}

void _project_line( uint32_t w, uint32_t h, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int& ox1, int& oy1, int& ox2, int& oy2 )
{
    struct point a, b;
    _sort_points( x1, y1, x2, y2, a, b );

    _screen_to_quad1( w, h, a.x, a.y );
    _screen_to_quad1( w, h, b.x, b.y );

    {
        float slope = _line_slope( a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y );
        float yint = _y_intercept( slope, a.x, a.y );
        if( yint >= 0 && yint < h )
        {
            ox1 = 0;
            oy1 = yint;
        }
        else
        {
            ox1 = _x_intercept( slope, yint );
            oy1 = 0;
        }
    }

    _quad1_to_screen( w, h, a.x, a.y );
    _quad1_to_screen( w, h, b.x, b.y );
    _quad1_to_screen( w, h, ox1, oy1 );

    _screen_to_quad3( w, h, a.x, a.y );
    _screen_to_quad3( w, h, b.x, b.y );

    {
        float slope = _line_slope( a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y );
        float yint = _y_intercept( slope, a.x, a.y );
        if( yint > -(int)h && yint < 0 )
        {
            ox2 = 0;
            oy2 = yint;
        }
        else
        {
            ox2 = _x_intercept( slope, yint );
            oy2 = 0;
        }
    }

    _quad3_to_screen( w, h, a.x, a.y );
    _quad3_to_screen( w, h, b.x, b.y );
    _quad3_to_screen( w, h, ox2, oy2 );

    printf("ox1=%d, oy1=%d, ox2=%d, oy2=%d\n",ox1,oy1,ox2,oy2);
}

    int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
    {
        int ox1, oy1, ox2, oy2;
        _project_line( 640, 480, 30, 50, 70, 20, ox1, oy1, ox2, oy2 );
        return 0;
    }
```

Here is a link to it on ideone: http://ideone.com/LaejBy

Output looks like this:

ox1=0, oy1=73, ox2=1316, oy2=0

The first point looks OK, and the y of the second point is correct for this line, but the second points X is way off.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?  (AKA creating an MCVE for us?)

Comment: Yes, I did. If you are implying that I haven't done enough work myself on this, then you are sorely mistaken. I have attempted a number of versions (for example, treating the line as the hypotenuse of a right triangle and using the tangent of angle to compute the opposite side of a right triangle between the edge of the screen and each point) but ran into other more complicated issues.

Comment: I'm implying that standard etiquette on SO is to produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This is definitely not one (~100 lines of code, no specific input/outputs for us to examine).

Comment: Ok, I added a link to Ideone and added its output.

Comment: This is still a poor question, as you're essentially asking us to debug 117 lines of code - are you saying that it's not possible to identify an earlier point in your program flow where behaviour deviated from what were you expecting, and then build a simpler test based around *that*?

Comment: Never mind. Asking a question around here is now more trouble than it's worth apparently as you are essentially requiring me to solve 99% of the problem myself before I ask it.

Comment: Learning to debug on your own is important. Find the simplest quadrant 3 data that produces what you think is a weird output. Work it by hand, doing the calculation you think your algorithm should. You'll probably find the error in the process. If not, get in a debugger or add a few print statements to see what it's actually computing. Find where the two sets of numbers diverge. That's the bug.

Comment: @dicroce - Yes, because the alternative is that someone else solves 99% of the problem for you by debugging your code.  And SO is **not** a crowdsourced debugging service - that's why we keep banging on about MCVEs every time someone posts 100+ lines of code.  You have a high rep, surely you've been around long enough to know the drill by now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a conceptually simpler approach. Call the points A and B. Use the parametric form:

```
x = xA + t(xB - xA)
y = yA + t(yB - yA)
```

Now find the values of t where the line touches the left and right boundaries xL and xR by solving the x equation

```
tL = (xL - xA) / (xB - xA)
tR = (xR - xA) / (xB - xA)
```

Just skip this computation if the line is vertical.

Then do the same for the top and bottom with the y equation:

```
tB = (yB - yA) / (yB - yA)
tT = (yT - yA) / (yB - yA)
```

Skip this if the line is horizontal.

Now from the 4 values tL, tR, tB, tT (or 2 if the input was horizontal or vertical), half the values will be negative and half positive (why?).  Pick the smallest absolute value in each case. This tells you the boundaries of intersections directly: left, right, bottom, top based on the respective t value. From this, one coordinate of each intersection (x or y) is obvious. To find the other, substitute into the relevant original parametric equation(s).